# How do I subtract two data frames in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes

```
df_1.columns = Index([ 1.0,  2.0,  3.0,  4.0,  5.0,  6.0,  7.0,  8.0,  9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0,
       13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0, 21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 24.0,
       25.0, 26.0, 27.0],
      dtype='object', name='delay_ist')

df_2.columns = Index([ 1.0,  2.0,  3.0,  4.0,  5.0,  6.0,  7.0,  8.0,  9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0,
           13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0, 21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 24.0,
           25.0, 26.0, 27.0],
          dtype='object', name='delay_ist')
```

I want df = df_1 - df_2
but when I do this I get the following error : `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`

I am also unable to drop this `delay_ist` from my dataframe. Can someone please help me with this?

```
delay_ist | 1.0 | 2.0 | 3.0 
0 | 23.3 | 34.4 | 12.7 
1 | 12.3 | 3.4 | 2.2

where 1.0 , 2.0 and 3.0 are columns and name = 'delay_ist'
```

df_2 is also exact same with different values but same column names.

Comment: Please provide your actual dataframes.

Comment: @ddejohn hello I have edited the question.

Comment: You've only provided one dataframe, and not one that is easily copy-paste-able. Please provide both dataframes for us to copy-paste and work on. Please also include the output of `df_1.dtypes` and `df_2.dtypes`.

Comment: The error is telling you that you're trying to subtract strings, which you can't do. Your data likely aren't numeric.

Answer (score 1):

I did the following and it worked. Thank you for spending time on this :)

```
def calculate_deltas_df(df, df_expected):
    df_dropped_cumulative_stats = df[df.columns[~df.columns.isin(['delay_ist','second_cycle','age','cycle_end_date','prime_tagging','Total','Pending','Mid_cycles'])]]
    df_dropped_expected = df_expected[df_expected.columns[~df_expected.columns.isin(['delay_ist','second_cycle','age','cycle_end_date','prime_tagging','Total','Pending','Mid_cycles'])]]
    del df_dropped_cumulative_stats.columns.name  #for dropping delay_ist
    del df_dropped_expected.columns.name
    df_delta = df_dropped_expected - df_dropped_cumulative_stats  #getting delta table from which we will calculated std dev , avg and flags
    return df_delta
```